# Load multiple files, check file name, archive a file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

In Data Fusion pipeline:

How do I read all the file names from a bucket and load some based on file name, archive others ?

Is it possible to run gsutil script from the Data Fusion pipeline ?

Sometimes more complex logic needs to be put in place to decide what files should be loaded. Need to go through all the files on a location then load only those that are with current date or higher. The date is in a file name as a suffix i.e. customer_accounts_2021_06_15.csv

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you are planning on writing the files to, you may be able to use the GCS Source plugin with the [logicalStartTime Macro](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/1188036697/Macros+and+macro+functions#Logical-Start-Time-function) in the `Regex Path Filter` field in order to filter on only files after a certain date. However, this may cause all your file data to be condensed down to record formats. If you want to retain each specific file in their original formats, you may want to consider writing [your own custom plugin](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/480313897/Developing+Plugins+Guide).